# Homology of $X \times I$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to compute $H_n(\Sigma_g \times S^1,\mathbb{R})$ (where $\Sigma_g$ is the a closed orientable surface of genus g). 
As part of the answer I wanted to use Mayer–Vietoris sequences since I though splitting the space up into 4 identical "tubes" (by splitting the space into 2 copies of $\Sigma_g \times A$  with $A$ being a bit more than half of $S^1$) would make things simpler. 
After some thinkinking I have come to the realization that I have no idea what taking the product by an interval gives me. \

So here is my question- 
given a topological space $X$ how can I describe the homology of $X\times [0,1]$ in relation to that of $X$. 
I believe the first homology group remains the same but suspect that for higher homology groups this is no longer the same. 
I do know that given a space $X$ we have $\tilde{H}_n(X)=\tilde{H}_{n+1}(SX)$ where $SX$ and thought I might be able to leverage this somehow but am unsure of how to remove the extra pair of points the suspension gives.
Thanks for the help

Comment: The interval $[0,1]$ is contractible, so $X\times[0,1]$ is homotopy equivalent to..?

Comment: Does that work for higher Homology groups too?

Comment: @MatanPinkas Homology groups are topological invariant, which means yes it works.